# Powering a Raspberry Pi Zero with a Li-po battery

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, battery-operated, lipo

I want to design a circuit to power a Raspberry Pi Zero using a single-cell Li-po battery (3.7 V).

I'm working on a portable hobby project that's required to be battery powered and allows recharging the battery and run while the battery is charging. The main controller board is a Raspberry Pi Zero. The final "product" will be enclosed in a box and will have a single USB-C input that will charge the whole thing (and allow it to work while connected to power).

I have very little experience with electronics so any input would be welcome.

Taking directions from [SparkFun's LiPo Fuel Gauge (MAX1704X) Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/lipo-fuel-gauge-max1704x-hookup-guide), I currently have a circuit similar to this:

[image]

Instead of the Arduino / FTDI pair on the right, I have my RPi Zero.

I tried connecting the positive power output from the Li-po charger directly to either a 5 V or 3.3 V input on the RPi Zero. When I do this, the Rpi Zero green light blinks but never goes steady, and I can't seem to SSH into it.

If I understand correctly, the issue is that I'm supposed to feed it 5 V, and perhaps my ~3.8 V input is not enough to power the RPi enough to boot up, or perhaps it's booting up but can't power its WiFi capabilities.

Do I need to use a "step up" / "boost" circuit to up the voltage to 5 V? Do I need to purchase a separate dedicated board or is this something I can construct with common electronics parts (resistors / capacitors / diodes that I may already have)?

Also, am I overall in the right direction for powering the RPi Zero using a battery?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [RPi Zero schematics](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpizero/raspberry-pi-zero-reduced-schematics.pdf), shows a PAM2306AYPKE which takes `5 V` from a USB connector and generates 3.3 V and 1.8 V supplies:

[image]

The [PAM2306 datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM2306.pdf) shows:

1. The *Recommended Operating Conditions* shows the Supply Voltage range is 2.5 to 5.5 V
2. Is a dual **step-down** current-mode, DC-DC converter. I.e. requires an input voltage greater than the output voltage.
3. The description shows the input is designed accept USB or a single single-cell LiPo battery:

   > The PAM2306 supports a range of input voltages from 2.5V to 5.5V,
   > allowing the use of a single Li+/Li-polymer cell, multiple Alkaline/NiMH
   > cell, USB, and other standard power sources.
4. The Efficiency VS Input Voltage graph shows that for a 3.3 V output, the input voltage can be as low as 3.5 V:

   [image]

So, in theory it should work with a single-cell LiPo battery (3.7V) connected to the input of the PAM2306.

> I tried connecting the positive power output from the Li-po charger directly to either a 5 V or 3.3 V input on the RPi Zero.

Connecting the Li-po to a 5 V pin on the header of the RPi Zero should avoid damage, since that connects to the supply input on the PAM2306.

However, connecting the Li-po to the 3.3 V pin on the header of the RPi Zero possibly caused some damage since:

1. Applied a higher than normal voltage `VDDIO2` pins on the `BCM2835` chip used on the RPi Zero, which expects nominally 3.3 V. The question text says the Li-po voltage is ~3.8 V, but a comment from @AndrewMorton said `the fully-charged voltage of a Li-Po cell is typically 4.2 V`. The only Broadcom document I can find for the `BCM2835` chip is a description of the peripherals. Since can't find a full datasheet don't know what the absolute maximum supply voltage is before permanent damage occurs.
2. Will only power the `BCM2835` via the `VDIO2` supply, and `PLL_1V8` supply won't be powered.

It might be worth checking if the RPi Zero still works if you power it over the USB connector. However, if the RPi Zero has been damaged due to supplying an over-voltage due to connecting the Li-po directly to a 3.3 V pin, perhaps try powering with a USB charger rather than connecting the RPi Zero to a PC USB port, in case the RPi Zero damages the PC.

---

Update in response to a comment:

> My RPi is luckily not damaged and works fine when connected to USB power. My battery currently outputs ~3.8V. I tried connecting it to either of the 5 V pins on my RPi Zero. It turns on the green power LED on the RPi, but it occasionally blinks and I can't seem to SSH to it at any point. AFAICT by using a multimeter, the voltage is pretty constant at 3.8V, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Any ideas? – [Amir Rachum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/6426/amir-rachum)

From a search have found other articles which suggest the RPi Zero can directly operate with a LiPo cell. The *Running the Pi Zero directly off the battery voltage* section of [Running a Raspberry Pi off a LiPo battery](https://www.richardmudhar.com/blog/2023/09/running-a-raspberry-pi-off-a-lipo-battery/) contains:

> With that proviso, I was surprised to read this [treatise on Hackaday](https://hackaday.io/project/19035-zerophone-a-raspberry-pi-smartphone/log/69596-a-guide-on-powering-pi-zero-directly-from-liion-batteries) that says the PiZero will work fine straight off a LiPo cell, the onboard regulator will still work down to 3.3V. The one provison is **DO NOT CONNECT A POWERED DEVICE TO USB**. You will be stuffing 5V bus power straight into your LiIon battery, result likely misery.

As to why are unable to use SSH to connect to the RPi Zero powered by a Li Po, perhaps trying to use networking increases the power consumption which causes the power supply voltages to dip below the minimum. In which case using an oscilloscope to monitor the 1.8 V and 3.3 V rails on the RPi Zero would help to check if that is happening.

Comment: And the last section of your answer is perhaps being optimistic, as the fully-charged voltage of a Li-Po cell is typically 4.2 V.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the feedback, have tried to edit the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Broadcom seem to like to keep the specs on their processors used in the Raspberry Pi series secret. Of course, no-one would expect a 3.3 V part to be tolerant to 4.2 V. Hope: yes; expect: no.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't what process technology the BCM2835 uses, but looking an example of a TI [TMS570LC4357](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tms570lc4357.pdf) which is an ARM Cortex-R MCU, the VCCIO supply is (a) min 3 V, typical 3.3 V,  3.6 V in the _Device Recommended Operating Conditions_ (b) –0.3 V min ,4.6 V max in the _Absolute Maximum Ratings_. I agree with your summary of ``Hope: yes; expect: no`` of if the BCM2835 is tolerant to 4.2 V on VDIO2 supply, in the absence of any published Broadcom documentation.

Comment: Just based on experience, over-voltaging a 3.3V processor with 4.2V may make it too unhappy to work, but usually won't damage it enough so that it won't work again when powered correctly.  Note that I would not expect it to be **undamaged** -- I would just expect that it may work again, for anywhere between a lifetime and a minute.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the help and sorry for the delay in response. My RPi is luckily not damaged and works fine when connected to USB power. My battery currently outputs ~3.8V. I tried connecting it to either of the 3.3V pins on my RPi Zero. It turns on the green power LED on the RPi, but it occasionally blinks and I can't seem to SSH to it at any point. AFAICT by using a multimeter, the voltage is pretty constant at 3.8V, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I meant to either of the *5V* pins of course.

Comment: @AmirRachum I have updated the answer to attempt to address your comment. Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/704582/edit) the question to include links to the RPi Zero, the Li Po battery and the Li Po charger.

Answer (score 2):

If connecting the LiPo directly to the +5V input to the Pi doesn't work, use a 5V output boost converter that's rated for the highest current you expect the Pi to pull.